# How to get the child of a gtklistboxrow?

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

If you add items in a listbox you do this with list_box.insert(); Now there is a item and you can select it. For my example its a entry (textbox). But now I want to press an Button and give me the value of the entry out. I found no function in the reference for the list_box or for the list_box_row to give back any compatible object. 
I tried stuff like this:

```
gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(gtk_list_box_get_selected_row(GTK_LIST_BOX(listbox)))); //listbox is a variable of typ GtkWidget and contains the listbox in
```

But its not working. Anyone have a solution for it? I mean it would be a bit useless to consider a listbox if you cant work with the selected stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GtkListBoxRow is a GtkContainer. Specifically a (single item) GtkBin:
https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkListBox.html#GtkListBoxRow

You should be able to call:

```
gtk_bin_get_child(GTK_BIN(listboxrow));
```

Note that a `GtkListBoxRow` can have only one child, though a `GtkListBox` can have multiple `GtkListBoxRows`.

Comment: It is the correct answer. Thanks. But listbox was my list_box. So for all futher guys who will read this the correct call to get it is: gtk_bin_get_child(GTK_BIN(gtk_list_box_get_selected_row(GTK_LIST_BOX(listbox))));

Comment: Thanks. I made a small edit to change listbox to listboxrow in my answer.